# Update object model with data MVC .Net Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpPost]
public string Update(string name, string value) {
    var property = new Models.Property {
        Prop = _db.PROPERTies.SingleOrDefault(p => p.id == 3)
    };

    property[name] = value;
    return name + " " + value;
}
```

I've trying to get to the "Prop" model inside the property object by passing in the key and value that I'm wanting to change.

```
name = "Prop.Title"
value = "Test 123
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Error   452 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Namespace.Models.Property'
```

Is there an alternative way to burrow into the "property" object?

**Models.Property**

```
namespace Namespace.Models
{
    public class Property
    {
        public PROPERTy Prop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**PROPERTy**

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.PROPERTIES")]
public partial class PROPERTy : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Title;
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Title", DbType="VarChar(100)")]
public string Title
{
    get
    {
        return this._Title;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._Title != value))
        {
            this.OnTitleChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._Title = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("Title");
            this.OnTitleChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In order to get it working I followed given advise and indexed the model.

```
object o = property;
object propValue = o.GetType().GetProperty(name.Split('.')[0]).GetValue(o, null);
propValue.GetType().GetProperty(name.Split('.')[1]).SetValue(propValue, Server.HtmlDecode(value), null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to use is an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx), but your class doesn't implement that "pattern".

The pattern is relatively simple to implement. At a minimum, add this:

```
public object this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        var pi = this.GetType().GetProperty(key); // find the property that matches the key
        return pi.GetValue(this, null);
    }
    set
    {
        var pi = this.GetType().GetProperty(key); // find the property that matches the key
        pi.SetValue(this, value, null);
    }
}
```

It's up to you to make sure that the class actually contains a property matching the key.

Comment: Absolutely right. Sorry Think I was working at bit too late last night. Thank you very much for this :)

Comment: hmmmm okay it's not working exactly as expected. I've tried passing the key as `Prop.Title` which the key does exist but obviously can't be accessed that way. So I've altered the code a little to look deeper. 

`var pi = GetType().GetProperty(key.Split('.')[0]);
var pii = pi.GetType().GetProperty(key.Split('.')[1]);
pii.SetValue(this, value, null);` But that's still not coming back with any results. `pi` is correctly getting set to the `Prop` model but it's the getting deeper bit I can't do.

Comment: I've sorted it. Thank you for the pointer in the right direction

Comment: `object o = property; object propValue = o.GetType().GetProperty(name.Split('.')[0]).GetValue(o, null); propValue.GetType().GetProperty(name.Split('.')[1]).SetValue(propValue, Server.HtmlDecode(value), null);`